# KaIOs - Kaiads Frequency capping in effect. kaios ads not resopond ontime

Tags: javascript, kaios

I want add kai-ads for a phaser 3 pong game when score is 5th, 10th, 15th, 20th. but its not work properly, and get error code 7 **(Frequency capping is the limit on how often the device can request for an ad, please try again later.)**

actually sometime 5th and 15th work fine.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You're hitting a rate limit, KaiAds limits ad requests to about 1 per 30 seconds

Comment: yes yes.. there is a frequency 40 second when  I asked kaios add team.. then I fixed that issue..  thank u respond @Tom